# How to compute the cross-correlation as quickly as possible

Tags: python, statsmodels

I have to compute the cross-correlation for a lot of pairs sequences. In fact I only care about the first 100 lags for each.

This is my code of the right scale with some made up data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.tsa.stattools as stattools

def create(n):
    x = np.zeros(n)
    for i in range(1, n):
        if np.random.rand() < 0.9:
            if np.random.rand() < 0.5:
                x[i] = x[i-1] + 1
        else:
            x[i] = np.random.randint(0,100)
    return x
x = create(4000)
y = create(4000)
plt.plot(stattools.ccf(x, y)[:100])
```

If I do

```
%timeit stattools.ccf(x, y)[:100]
```

I get

```
100 loops, best of 3: 10.7 ms per loop
```

It is possible to make this any faster?

Comment: @roganjosh It's just creating some random data.  This if statements says with 90% change there is a 50% change you add one to the value before. It's not really important for my question however. The data could be anything.

Comment: I was being slow sorry, I see what I was missing.

Comment: And actually, it's an interesting problem now I see it properly  :)

Comment: An immediate improvement would be to generate two arrays of random numbers and reference them by index rather than repeatedly call `np.random.rand()` to get single values on each iteration. But beyond that, it will take some thought to improve this.

Comment: @roganjosh It's the time calling ccf that is the problem. Curiously acf seems to be double the speed. E.g. %timeit stattools.acf(x) takes about 5ms.  I think it has to do essentially the same work as ccf.